# MVC3 URL Encoding Issue with Slash (/) %2f - Passing a slash in query string with MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have the following routing path defined in global.asax to handle two parameters in the url:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{page}/{th}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional, th = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

The first parameter is a URL of another website, i.e. www.othersite.com/about/.

Even if I encode the slashes to %2f it fails to route the URL correctly. I want to use something like this:

```
http://{mywebsite}/www.othersite.net%2fabout%2f/{parameter2}
```

I **do not** want to use Base64 encoding as I want the URL to be readable as above.

I'm using MVC 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [`following blog post`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) from Scott Hanselman where he explains some possible workarounds. But the conclusion is:

> After ALL this effort to get crazy stuff in the Request Path, it's
>   worth mentioning that simply keeping the values as a part of the Query
>   String (remember WAY back at the beginning of this post?) is easier,
>   cleaner, more flexible, and more secure.

So basically it would be better to use an url encoded query string parameter for this instead of trying to fight against IIS in a battle that you will probably lose.